# sparse matrix multiplication program openmp

Tags: openmp, sparse-matrix

I'm looking for any standard C program that uses OpenMP APIs for a sparse matrix-vector or matrix-matrix multiplications. Can anyone let me know if there are any such programs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not looking for an open-source library, you can try to have a look at the Intel MKL Sparse-BLAS level 2 and level 3 routines:

http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/updates/10.3.5/mklman/index.htm

These libraries should be multithreaded using OpenMP, as stated in the following page:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-using-intel-mkl-with-threaded-applications/

Comment: I would like to know whether actually anyone has solid experience with Intel's sparse subroutines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are looking for a 3rd party library to perform sparse matrix-matrix multiplications.

Have a look at this great Book (Introduction to Parallel Computing): http://www.scribd.com/doc/60118054/72/The-matrix%E2%80%93vector-multiplication-with-OpenMP

Comment: The OP is asking for libraries for *sparse* data (sparse matrices, sparse vectors).  Your link only seems to deal with traditional (i.e. dense) matrices, or am I missing something?

Comment: No, the book also have a realy big part about sparse matrix. There are also two  libs mentioned: LAPACK and how it works with it. As LAPACK is a default library for math with OpenMP, i don't understand the need for extra libs. Sorry if my post was unclear.

Comment: I think asking for a library is an absolutely justified question. Frequently it is very helpful and important to have thoroughly tested libraries at hand you can rely on. Programming everything yourself is completely against the mantra of reusing working code.

Comment: @Lucas, thats right, but there is a default library! LAPACK is best practice for OpenMP and it is mentioned in the book

Comment: @Thomas, if I wanted to use Lapack, I would also use de facto a third party library. Furthermore, Lapack does not include algorithms for sparse matrices http://www.netlib.org/lapack/. The question was also implicitly about blas routines and not lapack routines.